# Find the absolute minimum of the function $ f(x,y) = x^2+y^2 $ subject to the constraint $x^2+ 2y^2 = 1 $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I tried this question on a site and found that none of the answers were the ones I got. I think my calculations were right but my understanding of applying the correct theorems may have been off.

I found the derivatives with respect to x and y and got:

$f_x = 2x \quad$   $f_{xx} = 2 \quad $ $ f_{y} = 2y \quad $ $ f_{yy}=2 \quad $ $ f_{xy} = 0 $

The critical values are when $ 2x = 2y $ which is the line x = y. the fancy formula:

$ D = f_{xx}*f_{yy} - (f_{xy})^2 $ gives us  $D = 4$ always. So long as the point is a critical point, its a relative min. Since it is subject to the constraint, we need the values which satisfy   $x^2+ 2y^2 = 1 $. Those are ones where $ x=y$ so we look at $x^2+ 2x^2 = 1 \implies 3x^2= 1 \implies x = \pm1/\sqrt{3}$. Either works so when I plug it in to the original function, since $ x=y$, I get $ 2/3 $. Thus my absolute minimum.

Is my reasoning correct? or am I missing tools or using the tools incorrectly from multivariable Calculus?

Comment: Use Lagrange Multipliers

Comment: How did you get the critical points again? Anyway, this is a constrained extrema problem, so looking for the points where $\nabla f$ vanishes usually won't do the trick. You need to use either Lagrange multipliers, or go with a trick method: The constraint tells you that $x^2+2y^2=1$, from which we can solve $x^2=1-2y^2$. Therefore the function to be minimized is actually
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2=(1-2y^2)+y^2=1-y^2.$$
This suggests the plan: find the maximum of $y^2$ on the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=1$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From our constraint $x^2+2y^2=1$ we have $x^2=1-2y^2$ hence we can rewrite our function in terms of $y$:

$$f(y)=1-2y^2+y^2=1-y^2$$

With the constraint $y \in [-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]$ because $x^2 \geq 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

It should be clear that $f$ attains an absolute maximum at $1$ when $y=0$, and has absolute minimums of $\frac{1}{2}$ when $y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: The method of taking partial derivatives of $f$ helps at finding critical points but does not help you find the maximum/minimum at the boundary, and that is all we are interested in this problem. A usual alternative to what I wrote above are Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

To do the Lagrange method let 
$$F=x^2+y^2+\lambda(x^2+2y^2-1)$$

Then 
$$F_x=(1+\lambda)x=0$$
$$F_y=(1+2\lambda)y=0$$
$$F_{\lambda}=x^2+2y^2-1=0$$

Thus $x=0$ or $y=0$ the first gives the minimum, the second the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

As we have

$x^2+2y^2=1$

we can put

$$x=\cos(t)$$

and

$$y=\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

thus

$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos^2(t))$

so, the absolute minimum is

$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I get it. Thank you. Use la grange multipliers or parametric questions.

Comment: how do we use lagrange multipliers here?

Comment: don't you use the $(f_x,f_y) = \lambda(g_x,g_y) $?

Comment: I am not saying necessarily that he used it.

Comment: I think I get it. So you have to use a trick because $\deltaf$ does not vanish completely. but if the function were nicer, la grange multipliers would work in other cases.